# Spring boot single application with 2 controllers on 2 different hosts

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have:

```
public firstController() {
...
}

public secondController() {
...
}
```

I want to start every controller on different host. Is it possible to handle it by only single application with Spring Boot?

Comment: Not possible.  Running on separate hosts means two JARs deployed separately.

Comment: are you sure? What about Spring profiles?

Comment: It's still a single JAR.  You can use profiles to set values by environment, but it won't allow you to run part of the JAR on one server and the rest on another.  The executable JAR runs on one server at a time.  No getting around that, even with profiles.

Comment: So even with spring profiles they can have only single environment loaded?

Comment: Yes.  The profile applies to the entire deployment.  Deployments are quantized by host: one deployment, one host.  Not split.  When I use profiles, they are "default" when I run locally or "cloud" when I deploy the JAR to cloud.  I don't pick and choose where controllers are deployed, because they are all in the same JAR.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need two separate JARs if your intent is to run two different controllers on two different hosts.

There is no way to split a single deployment to run on different servers.

You can specify different profiles, but they apply to the entire deployment.  You can't split it up.

Answer (score 0):

Use Spring Profiles per host. Then use the env variable as input to the config properties to load. See https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.6.RELEASE/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-profile-specific-properties

Eg `app1` has an env var specifying `host1`

Your application loads `application-host1.properties` (or equivalent)

`app2` has env var specifying `host2` so that you can substitute this into the properties variable for `application.properties`.

On running locally you can then specify the `HOST_ID`, say, and load up the relevant configuration you want to test with.

`@ConfigurationProperties("application-${HOST_ID}.properties")`

in your `@Configuration` class

Spring allows you to also use `@DependsOn` to load various classes into the spring configuration context so you could combine this in so that only various controllers are loaded

Comment: this doesn't give nothing, I would need two single applications then.

Comment: No, you'd have 1 application + 2 (or more) application configs that load different configurations of the same application on a per host basis based on some pre-set environment variable.